# Unity: opaque area of image should be a collider, transparent area should not

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I'm fairly certain that I search every possible answer for this, so please forgive me if there is an answer somewhere...

I have a bunch (35) images that are procedurally assembled to make a "maze" of sorts. The "player" object is placed in a random position on the screen and I it should avoid the collidable space. The "maze" images are 2D with some opaque areas (white) and transparent areas (blue). In Unity, all of the images have Polygon Colliders that are using Composite... All of this works perfectly, except...

My issue is that Polygon Colliders use outlines or polygons, but everything in between is not a collider. That means that, unless the player hits one of the edges of the collider, it won't register an actual collision.

To better understand this, look at the image. The player will spawn in the opaque area of the image, when I want that area to be a collider.

Btw, not using Composite produces the same issue, where the player object spawns between the polygon edges.

Any idea how to make the entire opaque area a collider?

[image: Collision Issue]

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a collision within the collider by using the `void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)` method for whichever object that you want to handle the test.

However, if you're trying to use the collider to determine whether an area is safe to spawn in, you might want to check whether the spawnpoint is inside the collider using `collider.bounds.Contains(player.transform.position)` (or whatever position you'd like to check).

Check the documentation for more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html

Comment: I'm already doing a successful collider check, although with a Polygon Collider the only collision "area" is the edges. I will check the Bounds.Contains technique. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `OnCollisionStay2D` to detect collisions within the collider area?  I just tested it and it registers the collision fine without needing to touch a collider edge.

Comment: I have tried and it isn't working for me, but I may have a variable communication issue, which is causing problems. I'm doing some additional testing and I'll get back here when I know more.

Comment: I'm also wondering if this is an issue that's occurring based on the fact that all of the colliders (maze and player) are instantiating and something isn't getting called correctly.